# Timeline Detection

Tags: nlp, data-mining

I am trying to do a timeline detection problem using text classification. As a newbie I am confused as to how I can go about with this. Is this  a classification problem? i.e, Can I use the years(timelines) as outcomes and solve this as a classification problem?

Comment: What is timeline detection and why do you think it is amenable to text classification?

Comment: time line detection is like finding which period the text belongs to. for example if i use movie scripts, based on the pattern i should be able to find the period in which it took place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to solve this as a classification problem as you suggest. An option could be to find or build a corpus consisting of texts tagged with the period in which they're set, and train a classification algorithm on this data set.

Another option could be to train a [word space model](http://www.sics.se/~mange/papers/RI_intro.pdf) on such a data set, and generate vectors for different periods of time (e.g. the 50s, 60s etc.). You could then create a document vector for the text you wish to classify, and find which of these time vectors yields the best match.

Might not work, but it could be interesting to see what results you get.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you ver much Bjerva..that greatly helps